# Batch file to execute java program

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

I have multiple .java files inside a folder (e.g temp/code/project)
I want a batch file that will compile and run these java files.
The batch file should  create class files inside the same structure where java files are located starting with the classes folder (i.e classes/temp/code/project)

I don't know how to write a batch file. Can any body help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically you should write the following:

```
@echo off
::compile classes
javac -cp YOUR_CLASSPATH com/yourcompany/YourClass1.java
javac -cp YOUR_CLASSPATH com/yourcompany/YourClass2.java
javac -cp YOUR_CLASSPATH com/yourcompany/YourClass3.java
javac -cp YOUR_CLASSPATH com/yourcompany/YourClassLauncher.java
:: create jar
jar cvfM Manifest.txt myjar.jar *.class
echo.
echo Hit any key to launch project.
pause
java -jar myjar.jar
pause
```

If you have one class that depends on all other classes in your project it is enough to run javac with this class only: compiler will compile everything.

```
# Manifest.txt
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .;MyUtils.jar
Created-By: 1.6.0
Main-Class: com.yourcompany.YourClassLauncher
```

This is only example and a good exercise. In real life people use special build tools like good old Ant, Maven or newer Graidle or Buildr. I'd recommend you to take one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of

```
cd C:\temp\code\project
javac -classpath . -d C:\classes\temp\code\project\ *.java
```

You may not need to include the -classpath tag (I always do so that I don't have to worry about maintaining my CLASSPATH variable. The -d tag specifies a particular directory to place generated class files.

Comment: :But we have to manually create destination folders.Can't it be automated